# Skydrive creates a .lnk file after I upload a folder

Tags: onedrive

I have installed Skydrive on my PC which uses Windows 7, and when I drag a folder across to my skydrive folder on my pc, i then have the green tick, but when I look on Outlook.com, all I see is a .lnk file with the same name as my folder, not the folder I have copied across or its contents. e.g. dragged across folder called 'steve' to skydrive folder on pc, it shows with a green tick next to it in the skydrive folder, but when I look on web Outlook (https://skydrive.live.com), all I see is 'steve.lnk' if I click that it says 'downloaded' !? When I look at the download file its 6k and just seems rubbish.  Oddly, I have tried the same thing with a folder which has only a few files, and it works fine. Can anyone help?

Comment: It seems like you copied a shortcut instead of the folder itself.

Comment: you are right, thanks very much for putting me out of my misery :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to @FSMaxB for answering this for me above. This could have proved to be a costly error further down the line, glad I queried this.

"It seems like you copied a shortcut instead of the folder itself. – FSMaxB "